# Remove audio *only* from an MP3 file

Tags: mp3, metadata

I'd like to remove **audio** from an mp3 file, while leaving its metadata
intact (an ID3 tag, v2.3 in this case).

I'd like to do this in bulk, against many files, if possible.

Are there any tools that can do this? The best thing I can think of is [vim-as-a-hex-editor](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2234) and a macro to find the end of header and delete what follows, but that approach feels a lot like using a hammer as a can opener and I'd rather avoid it.

(To be clear, I'm not asking how to strip the metadata, which is covered in many other questions. I only care about the metadata, and want to minimize file size.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using ffmpeg on the mp3 files with the `-aframes` option set to `1`. Metadata will be kept, while the audio will be close to non-existent.

In powershell, use the command:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\path\where\to music\files" | foreach-object { ffmpeg.exe -i $_.Name -c copy -aframes 1 (Join-Path "c:\path\where\to copy\output\" $_.Name) }
```

Comment: Wonderful. The `-aframes` is what I was looking for. Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

A version of @Reddy's PS answer to do the same job from a Unix-like shell

```sh
# From PWD /path/where/to/music/files
for f in *.mp3 ; do ffmpeg -i "${f}" -c copy -aframes 1 "path/where/to/copy/output/${f}"; done
```